# The report server can’t connect to its database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to configure an instance of SSRS, but with little success.

I've installed SSRS on the server DWHFRONT. It runs under the Network Service credentials. On the Database tab of the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, I've set it up to use a database on DWHBACK, which it created succesfully. The connection uses a domain account DOM\SA_DWH. I've added a Login to the server DWHBACK for DOM\SA_DWH, and I can see that the Reporting Services Manager added the authorisations to the SSRS-databases. The Configuration Manager accepts these connection parameters.

However (after setting up the URLs, Virtual Directories etc) if I visit the URL of DWHFRONT/Reports/, I get an error saying:

> **The service is not available.**
>
> The report server isn’t configured properly. Contact your system administrator to resolve the issue. System administrators: The report server can’t connect to its database because it doesn’t have permission to do so. Use Reporting Services Configuration Manager to update the report server database credentials.

At first I thought it might be an issue because there is noting deployed to the SSRS instance yet. When I try to deploy something however, I get this error in BIDS:

> The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer)

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server has been configured correctly to use the domain login? The phrase "I created a login DWHBACK for DOM\SQ_DWH" strikes me initially as not being necessary?

Comment: @DavidW If I don't create a login for DOMAIN\SA_DWH, the user can't connect to the server... And I only created a server-level login; the rights for the databases SSRS, SSRS_TEMP and a special role for Master and MSDB were all created by the SSRS config tool.

Comment: Well my thought was that if SQL Server has been configured for mixed-mode security you don't have to create a separate login - that is, you should be able to import a full AD account (DOM\SA_DWH) directly from the Logins dialog....

Comment: @DavidW That *is* how I created the login.

Comment: But in the text of your post, you said you "created a login DWHBACK for DOM\SA_DWH," and that's not really the same as importing the AD identity for the domain account....perhaps I'm misinterpreting what was posted.

Comment: @DavidW Literally (end unedited): "I've added a Login to the server DWHBACK for DOM\SA_DWH", by which I mean: Expanded Security, right-clicked Logins, New Login, DOM\SA_DWH [x] Windows Authentication.

Comment: Good enough, then; that was the first thing that came to my mind. Sorry not to be of more help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166974/discussion-between-steenbergh-and-david-w).

Comment: could be firewall blocking connection.

Comment: I wrote "It runs under the Network Service credentials". Have you tried to change the service and run it under a domain account that has permission on the database server?

Comment: Please check to see if SQL Web browser is enabled. In SQL server configuration manager properties, turn start mode to automatic and enable the service.

Comment: @steenbergh if your database isn't local to the SSRS service host, and it sounds like it isn't?, this could be a "double-hop" issue. Try [enabling remote errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-remote-errors-reporting-services), if you see the error "login failed for user NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" when connecting to your report portal then this is most likely the case.

Comment: You will need to add your Report Server machine name to SQL Server logins. It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, It put me on the right track!

The Domain Account SA_DWH was prohibited from interactive logon. SSRS apparently does require this. The Interactive Logon restriction was lifted and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check SQL Logs for any error
2. Run SQL Profile on SQL Server to catch any connection/permissions errors
3. Try to re-enter permissions for a domain account
4. Check a domain account is not disabled / locked / password expired
5. Try to run SSRS Service under same AD account that connects Report Server DB.
6. Try to enable also Named Pipes on both servers (protocols and client protocols)
7. Try to delete encryption keys and to re-create them.
8. Try another domain user and check granted permissions in all DBs (ReportServer, ReportServer Temp, msdb), check if DB user in each DB maps to the valid SID)
9. Try to grant SQL server sysadmin permissions for that AD account (temporary).
10. Check SSRS Logs for any errors (it's good if you attach them).
11. Check Event Viewer --> Security --> Failed Audit on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Can you perform following test to check will it resolve your issue?:

1. Add account [DOM\DWHFRONT$] with temporary high privileges, like
   SYSADMIN to SQL Instance DWHBACK   (SA is a temporal measure, to be removed after test)
2. Change SSRS Service account to: "Local System"
3. Recreate ReportServer database and choose credentials: "Service Credentials"

p.s. we had issues with recent versions of SSRS running under Network Service credentials..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a "double-hop" issue.

This can be confirmed by [enabling remote errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-remote-errors-reporting-services) on the Reporting Services instance. Then, when you connect to the report portal you should see your original error along with "login failed for user NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON". If so, then it is highly likely that this is a Kerberos delegation issue.

When you host the SSRS service and the target database on different servers, you will almost always experience the "double-hop" issue, which will require Kerberos delegation to be configured to enable SSRS to reuse the user credentials to access the database across servers.

[Pinal Dave](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/13/sql-server-login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon/) wrote a nice blog about this in the context of SQL Server.

To enable delegation, you first need to ensure you have your SPNs configured correctly. [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046) is a great utility to help with this. I would run this on both your SSRS server AND your database server to ensure both servers have their SPNs configured correctly.

Once you have your SPNs configured, you then need to [enable delegation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/autz_auth_stuff/2011/05/03/kerberos-delegation/) in Active Directory. This will need to be done for your DOM\SA_DWH account.

Comment: Why would it be 'double-hop'? I have User X interacting with the SSRS webservice, and that webservice uses a completely different set of Credentials (SA_DWH) to connect to the datbase. Two single-hops. in my view...

Comment: Do you understand what the concept of delegation is? Double-hop is the phraseology used to describe the action of the user’s credentials being passed on to secondary connections... even if you think it’s two single hops. [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/) explains the basic concept. Essentially, SSRS needs permission to pass on the user credentials to a separate server via a new connection. Otherwise how would you authenticate user access to the database, or against schemas, or row-level security?